# Google fit sleep datatype is missing from Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to get sleep data in my **Xamarin Forms App** from google fit and i can't find sleep datatype in Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType

```
 SessionReadRequest sessionReadRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()                
                .ReadSessionsFromAllApps()                
                 .Read(**DataType.????**)
                .SetTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)
                .Build();
```

Also according to following url
https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-sleep-data

I should have .IncludeSleepSessions() in my builder but there is nothing like this available!!!!

Comment: I need help with xamarin forms and google fitness. Do you have a github I can take a look at with what you're trying to do? I woulld like to study if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested and the `DataType` is under `Android.Gms.Fitness.Data;`.

Here is the steps:

Change your Android project TargetFramework to Android 10.

Install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Fitness` with version 118.0.0 in Nuget package Manager.

Then using the NameSpace:

```
using Android.Gms.Fitness;
using Android.Gms.Fitness.Request;
using Android.Gms.Fitness.Data;
```

After that, I can find the DataType:

```
    SessionReadRequest sessionReadRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
       .ReadSessionsFromAllApps()
        .Read(DataType.TypeSpeed)
       .SetTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)
       .Build();
```

If you still can't find it, you can try to re-install the package, clean/rebuild the project and then try again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not talking about DataType.TypeSpeed. I am looking for SLEEP.

Comment: OK, I can't find `Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.SleepStages` too.  You can open an issue in Github to report this problem.

Comment: @Queueli Can you please share the linker here if you opened an issue?

Comment: Thanks Jack. Can you please explain what do you mean by share the linker? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's typo. I mean share the issue link if you opened an issue in Github:).